# How to compare two List of Dictionary values and put new key into dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my code

```
public class model 
{
    public model();

    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
}

List<Dictionary<string,string>>  data1;
List<Dictionary<string,string>>  data2;

var data1=await get<model>();
var data2=await get<model>();

data1[0]=[0][{id,101}]
         [1][{name,one}]

data1[1]=[0][{id,102}]
         [1][{name,two}]

data1[2]=[0][{id,103}]
         [1][{name,three}]


data2[0]=[0][{user.id,102}]
```

Finally I want output like

```
data1[0]=[0][{id,101}]
         [1][{name,one}]
         [2][{active,false}]

data1[1]=[0][{id,102}]
         [1][{name,two}]
         [2][{active,true}]

data1[2]=[0][{id,103}]
         [1][{name,three}]
         [2][{active,false}]
```

in the above code i have two list of dictionaries,the first dictionary contains 2 keys like id and name , second dictionay contains one key id . i want to compare id keys in two dictionaries when id match put new key with value(true/false) into first dictionary.

Comment: Rather than using those dictionaries they should just be objects of a new class representing what these objects are.

Comment: no i have a model like public class model{ public list<dictionary<string,string>> {get;set'};}

Comment: Then you should change your model.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data1.ForEach(dict => dict.Add("active", data2.Any(x=> x.ContainsKey("user.id") && x["user.id"] == dict["id"]).ToString()));
```

Comment: Thank You @Nikolay. Now its working fine , and i have one more question